# Newly created list item doesn't always trigger event via Socket IO

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, socket.io

Trying to create an event item that triggers on every new list item generated by socket IO client side but it is not working

moving around the event inside DOMcontentloaded and also while i am making the list

```
 socket.on('chatroom created', chatroom => {
     const li = document.createElement('li');
     li.innerHTML = `${chatroom}`;
     li.classList.add('chats');
     document.querySelector('#chatrooms').append(li);
     document.querySelector('#chatroom-name').value = '';
     document.querySelector('.chats').onclick = () => {
       alert("hey there")
     };
   });
```

Only the first list item has the onclick functionality. But not the other ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using `querySelector` which only selects the first element. Use `querySelectorAll` and iterate through them to add all the listeners:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".chats").forEach(elem => elem.onclick = () => alert("hey there"));
```